# How to read a text file column by column in php or javascript

Tags: javascript, php

I'm new to PHP/JavaScript and have no idea how do I write code to extract data from a text file using PHP/JavaScript.

Data:

```
-bash-4.1$ cat Data/data/XYZ.txt
        XYZ    -       -       -
        Day1    12      28      MCS
        Day2    15      30      PCS
        Day3    18      28      LH
        Day4    11      26      SUN
        Day5    20      34      RA
        Day6    16      26      PCS
        Day7    6       15      FO
-bash-4.1$
```

I want to have 4 variable which should have values:

```
v1=Day1 v2=12 v3=28 and v4=MCS**
```

What I have done is I have extracted only first string from the file, code for same is given below.

```
<?php 
echo '<p>Hello World</p>';  
$myfile = fopen("Data/data/XYZ.txt", "r") or die("Unable to open file!");
$line=fgets($myfile);
echo $line;
fclose($myfile);?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. Outputs:

```
v1=Day1 v2=12 v3=28 v4=MCS
v1=Day2 v2=15 v3=30 v4=PCS
v1=Day3 v2=18 v3=28 v4=LH
v1=Day4 v2=11 v3=26 v4=SUN
v1=Day5 v2=20 v3=34 v4=RA
v1=Day6 v2=16 v3=26 v4=PCS
v1=Day7 v2=6 v3=15 v4=FO
```

See comments for a step-by-step explanation:

```
<?php

// Input specified as string for the sake of this demo.
$inputData = <<<EOT
        XYZ    -       -       -
        Day1    12      28      MCS
        Day2    15      30      PCS
        Day3    18      28      LH
        Day4    11      26      SUN
        Day5    20      34      RA
        Day6    16      26      PCS
        Day7    6       15      FO
EOT;
// Split string on EOL character, into array.
$input = explode(PHP_EOL, $inputData);

// Or, if you're reading from a file, comment everything above and uncomment the following line:
// $input = file('Data/data/XYZ.txt');

// $input is now an array, and allows us to iterate over it using foreach.
// $rowIndex will hold the array index, $line will hold a single line from the input.
foreach ($input as $rowIndex => $line)
{
    // Skip header.
    if ($rowIndex == 0)
        continue;

    // Trim any unwanted leading whitespace, so the resulting array starts with a usable value.
    // preg_split() will split the line on whitespace, and return an array of all column values.
    $cols = preg_split('/[\s]+/', trim($line));

    // You can now read out the array of column values however you see fit.
    $v1 = $cols[0];
    $v2 = $cols[1];
    $v3 = $cols[2];
    $v4 = $cols[3];

    echo "v1=$v1 v2=$v2 v3=$v3 v4=$v4<br>\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Steps:

1) You can open the file using [fopen](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php) and you will get the contents as a string.

2) Split ([explode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)) the resultant string by new line character.

3) Now loop over the array we got from step 2). In every iteration, you will get a line from file.

Code:

```
<?php
// Open the file
$filename = 'xyz.txt';
$fp = fopen($filename, 'r'); 

// Add each line to an array
if ($fp) {
   $array = explode("\n", fread($fp, filesize($filename)));
}
if (! empty($array)) {
    foreach ($array as $line) {
        $cols = preg_split('/[\s]+/', trim($line));
        echo '<pre>';print_r($cols);echo '</pre>';
    }
}
?>
```

Response:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Day1
    [1] => 12
    [2] => 28
    [3] => MCS
)

Array
(
    [0] => Day2
    [1] => 15
    [2] => 30
    [3] => PCS
)

Array
(
    [0] => Day3
    [1] => 18
    [2] => 28
    [3] => LH
)

Array
(
    [0] => Day4
    [1] => 11
    [2] => 26
    [3] => SUN
)

Array
(
    [0] => Day5
    [1] => 20
    [2] => 34
    [3] => RA
)

Array
(
    [0] => Day6
    [1] => 16
    [2] => 26
    [3] => PCS
)

Array
(
    [0] => Day7
    [1] => 6
    [2] => 15
    [3] => FO
)
```

Comment: Can I have separate values like v1=Day1  v2=12 v3=28 and v4=MCS , I want to break up the string and hold values in separate variables

Comment: Please refer Ro Achterberg's answer.